# How to get touchDown events invoked within a UIScrollView during dragging?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, touch, forward

I have a UIScrollView, containing a UIView that contains some buttons with event on their Touch Down.

As the scrollView gets dragged, the buttons just never get their invocations.

If I turn delayContentTouches off, the scrollView just cannot be dragged (I have full-sized buttons in it).

What now?

-Override something in a UIScrollVIew subclass?

-Or just implement some delegate methods?

-What is the best practice here?